# Why won't the screen refresh in PyGame?

Tags: pygame

I'm relatively new to PyGame. I'm trying to make a simple program to show a string denoting the mouse position on the screen.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400),0,32)
myFont = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 14)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    label = myFont.render('mouse coords: ' + str(x) + ', ' + str(y), 1, (0,128,255))

    screen.blit(label, (10,10))
    pygame.display.update()
```

When I move the mouse around, the label becomes blurry until the text is unreadable. I'm sure I'm calling screen.blit() and pygame.display.update() correctly, but yet the label doesn't seem to update! Any help would be great.

Comment: Clear the screen first, using `screen.fill(Color("black"))` , at the start of your draw logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you need to do is blit a background in the loop becuase what oure doing is blitting the mousecoords one on top of eachother

do something like this:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400),0,32)
myFont = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 14)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    label = myFont.render('mouse coords: ' + str(x) + ', ' + str(y), 1, (0,128,255))
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(label, (10,10))
    pygame.display.update()
```

this way you are filling the screen with black in between each update so the mouse pos is being blitted then its cleared by the fill then the new pos is being blitted and so on